# Problems with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new in Spring framewrok and I watched a Spring Boot tutorial and now I want to practise but when I run the app and I want to reach the url I get a whitelabel error page if I use the @Controller annotation.
Here is the error message: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

I tried to remove the @Controller annotation and use the @RestController. In this case I do not get the whitelabel page but the required html page does not show up, I only get back the returned string, my case it's "users/saveUserForm"

I use thymeleaf in the project

Here is my Controller class:

```
package com.teszt.thymeleaftest.controller;

import com.teszt.thymeleaftest.entity.Users;
import com.teszt.thymeleaftest.service.UsersService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private UsersService usersService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UsersService usersService) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/showUserForm")
    public String saveUser(Model theModel){

        //create model attribute to bind form data
        Users theUser = new Users();

        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);

        return "users/saveUserForm";
    }


}
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.teszt</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaftest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>thymeleaftest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: localhost:8080/users/showUserForm

Comment: It sounds like you do in fact reach the Controller (as you get something with @RestController), but maybe the Thymeleaf template ist not found.

Comment: I put my html file(s) under resources/templates/users. Is that the problem? I'm using intelliJ btw

Comment: Try replacing the thymeleaf dependency in your pom with Spring Boot's Thymeleaf starter. If you don't all of Spring Boot's Thymeleaf magic won't happen.

Comment: @LeeGreiner it helped my index page, so that is working right now but when i want to reach the /users/showUserForm still not working

Comment: Update, I changed the RestController to Controller and now its working

Comment: What you are returning is plain text as a response. In order to redirect you need to return as 
 "redirect:/users/saveUserForm";